# Realm Nested Object sort

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I have json:

```
{
 "title": "Title 2",
 "body": "Body 2",
 "status_info": {
            "is_favorite": false,
            "is_like": false,
            "like_count": 0
        },
 "id": "47e7704e-89f1-4d0d-8da1-52a080d56f46"
}
```

And two Realm Objects:

```
open class Actuality : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey lateinit var id: String
    @SerializedName("status_info")
    lateinit var statusInfo: StatusInfo
   ...
}

open class StatusInfo : RealmObject() {

    @SerializedName("is_like")
    var isLiked: Boolean = false

    @SerializedName("is_favorite")
    var isFavorite: Boolean = false

    @SerializedName("like_count")
    var likeCount: Int = -1
}
```

And i using RealmAdapter RealmResults for realtime updates,
but i have problem, when trying to sort Actualities by likeCount.

I tryed

```
data?.sort("likeCount", Sort.DESCENDING)
data?.sort("statusInfo.likeCount", Sort.DESCENDING)
```

But realm throws me exception, that "Field name 'likeCount' does not exist."
How i can handle realm nested object in RealmResults?

Comment: Link sorts are not yet supported, have a reverse relation to the parent and query the class you want to sort on

Comment: @EpicPandaForce add this as answer ;-)

Comment: @piotrek1543 it went to "in progress" just Today, so I'm waiting for the opportunity to say it works since whatever version :p

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how do you relate child to parent? Can you give an example :) Thanks

Comment: @berkayk Read more here about manual backlinks https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u